# R shiny barplot

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart

I have character data named "Sources" which are like this: (got to know it is character data using typeof operator)

```
A
B
C
D 
E 
F
```

I have some integer data called "Values" which are like this:

```
55
105
219
20
456
667
```

I want to build a barplot in R, so that "Sources" are on Y axis, and the "Values" are on X-axis. I tried the following, but did not get the result.

```
barplot(Values,names.arg=Sources,xlab="No of Values Connections",ylab="Source Name",main="Barplot of values")
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just need to add `horiz=TRUE`

Comment: Thanks for the help!